# Rendering all bands offers only 3 options instead of multiple

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, rendering

I am very new to remote sensing using QGIS.

I dont understand why sometimes when rendering all the bands, I only get 3 options instead of multiple. I am using sentinel 2 and I am trying to make a false composite image. The layer is a virtual raster layer.

Is there something I need to do in order to make sentinel 2 imagery render the way I want it to? (a false composite image).

SCP is installed.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with the rendering? [Which bands](https://gisgeography.com/sentinel-2-bands-combinations/) do you want to use? How did you create the Virtual raster, which input bands did you use and in which order?

Comment: video creating false colour virtual raster https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI5MtfUnUP4

Answer (score 1):

There´s no problem, you can only choose three bands because of the representation, you can choose only one band per chanel of color, red, green and blue, (RGB). It is ok. Please, look at these https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-2/false_color_infrared/ .

Comment: In addition, each channel sets the brightness level from 0 to 255 from min to max value